# How do you sum non integer values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Since the `SUM` function only returns `INT`, what function can you use to sum non-integer values like float, decimal or money?

I've seen some claims that the return type of SUM adjusts based on the data types you give it but that is not the case. It only returns `INT`. I've given it `FLOAT`, `DECIMAL` and `MONEY`, all return `INT`.

Here's an example query:
PayAmount is type `MONEY`, FXRate is type `FLOAT`

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
       SUM(PayAmount * FXRate) AS AmountInUSD
FROM EmployeeTransactions
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

Or with conversion:

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
       SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,6), PayAmount * FXRate)) AS AmountInUSD
FROM EmployeeTransactions
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

Still fails.

Example with constants:

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
       SUM(3.14159 * 2.365) AS AmountInUSD
FROM EmployeeTransactions
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

Result should be 7.42986035. SQL Server returns 7.

Answer (score 1):

`SUM` does not only return `int`. [The type returned by `SUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) depends is the most precise type of the provided expressions.

Consider this query:

```
SELECT SUM(3.14159 * 2.365) AS AmountInUSD;
```

Result:

```
+-------------+
| AmountInUSD |
+-------------+
|  7.42986035 |
+-------------+
```

The actual data type returned above is `numeric(38,8)` as can be determined with [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql):

Result:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT SUM(3.14159 * 2.365) AS AmountInUSD;';

+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------+-------+-----+
| is_hidden | column_ordinal |    name     | is_nullable | system_type_id | system_type_name | max_length | precision | scale | ... |
+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------+-------+-----+
|         0 |              1 | AmountInUSD |           1 |            108 | numeric(38,8)    |         17 |        38 |     8 | ... |
+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid funny business of multiplying a FLOAT data type, perhaps try something like this?

```
; WITH t as (SELECT EmployeeID, CAST(PayAmount AS DECIMAL(12,5)) as PayAmount, --or adjust 12,5 as needed
       CAST(FXRate AS DECIMAL(12,3)) as FxRate --or adjust 12,3 as needed
FROM EmployeeTransactions)
SELECT EmployeeId, SUM(PayAmount * FxRate) AS AmountInUSD
FROM t
GROUP BY EmployeeId;
```